# Block IP address which matches a rule

Tags: iptables

The following will drop packets which contain the string specified:

iptables -I FORWARD -j DROP -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 -m string --string "therichsheickc@yahoo.com"

The string is one which a botnet spammer uses (from 1000's upon 1000's of ip addresses) to hammer my email servers constantly. This rule is somewhat effective, but doesn't stop the connections. I'd like it to -j DROP the IP as well after a match. Can I do this in iptables without going to userspace?

Comment: What about using a tool as fail2ban ?

Comment: fail2ban could work but it is userspace.

Answer (score 2):

This particular scanner always greet with `EHLO 192.168.2.33`. Use these rules to stop them:

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i eth+ -p tcp --dport 25 -m string --string "192.168.2.33" --algo bm -m recent --set --name SBOT
iptables -I INPUT -i eth+ -p tcp --dport 25 -m recent --rcheck --name SBOT -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

or maybe this will help :

iptables -A FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "therichsheickc@yahoo.com" -j DROP